# Confidence level of effort estimates in JIRA

Tags: jira

What (%) number shall I put under confidence level estimate in JIRA when accepting requirements?

I understand that theoretically, 100% is ideal, but does 80% seem good enough given that I am comfortable with my estimates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The confidence level really should vary on a issue by issue basis.  There are several factors that can increase my confidence level on a task, which can include:

- The vagueness of the requirement being built.
- My familiarity with the technology/stack/libraries being worked on.
- My familiarity with the codebase(s)
- Whether the item has been done before.
- Am I introducing/using any new libraries/frameworks that I am not familiar with.
- The existence of automated testing on the existing modules/projects.
- The complexity of the feature/issue being added.